# background image in inline css style inside my html.erb view page is showing in development only but not production stage on heroku

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, heroku, background-image, production

I'm creating a new rails project and trying to refactor front-end site template inside it, I got to edit the background image css inline styling inside my html.erb file to match the Ruby on Rails conventions, but the background image **only shows on development stage, but not showing on production after pushing to heroku**, any solutions ? ... knowing that I'm still newbie to ruby on rails and refactoring themes, and that I searched various threads on stackoverflow and nothing works for me

here's the code I use

```
<div class="main_slider" style="background-image:url(/assets/slider_1.jpg)">
```

the code is used inside my **index.html.erb** file, in this part of the code

```
<div class="main_slider" style="background-image:url(/assets/slider_1.jpg)">
    <div class="container fill_height">
        <div class="row align-items-center fill_height">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="main_slider_content">
                    <h6>Spring / Summer Collection 2017</h6>
                    <h1>Get up to 30% Off New Arrivals</h1>
                    <div class="red_button shop_now_button"><a href="#">shop now</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

any solutions to make the background image appears in the production too ?, it's been a headache for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `image_path` or `image_url` instead of path to image on your directory, as images precompiled in production mode.
Change to this:

```
<div style="background-image:url(<%= image_url('myimage.jpg') %>)"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your problem be to do with rake assets:precompile and your production environment

You can try this:

```
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```